# pytest import a class from a parent directory result in a ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have my project directory like thisone:

```
README.md
athomcore.py
test
    |_unit
        |_test_one.py
        |___init__.py
```

for my testing purposes i have to import a class into athomcore.py file and i do:

```
import pytest
import sys
sys.path.append("...")
from ...athomcore import StatusDevice

def test_initial_status():
    mydev = StatusDevice(True)
    assert mydev.status == True
```

but when i run `pytest` in my terminal i get:

> ERROR test/unit/test_one.py - ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

How can i import class modules from my project for testing it?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong here. First off you should try to avoid using `sys.path.append` whenever possible. Secondly the path `...` is not valid, perhaps you mean `..`? In any case it is not needed here. If you run the tests from the root of the repository no path manipulation is needed. I replicated your repository structure and have the following set up.

```
├── athomcore.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_one.py
```

From the root of the repository, i.e the top level of the directory I run `pytest /tests` and the tests pass and run as expected for me.

```
================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/stackoverflow
collected 1 item                                                                         

tests/unit/test_one.py .                                                           [100%]

=================================== 1 passed in 0.03s ====================================
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html) about how `pytest` works with your path to set up tests.

Comment: > If you run the tests from the root of the repository no path manipulation is needed.

<=== THIS ===